# Importing GSpread File in Google Cloud Console Conflicts With Flask App; JSON Api Key Present

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, gspread

I have been able to deploy a flask app relatively easily with the proper docker configuration in Google Cloud Console. I am running this within a docker container. However, using gspread (with relevant authorization json file) does not permit me to deploy use flask app.
When I run the same code from a Python script in the same container without Flask, I can verify Gspread script is ok.

I show the Dockerfile below:

```py
# Python image to use.
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy the requirements file used for dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the working directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Run app.py when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

However, when I attempt to add an import of Gspread, with the relevant permissions in code like this:

```py
import flask  


import gspread
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gauth = "XXX.json"
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("/home/XXX.json", scopes) 
#access the json key you downloaded earlier 
client = gspread.authorize(credentials) 
# https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python
api_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = api_service.files().list( 
                            spaces = 'drive',\
                            supportsAllDrives = True,\
                                fields='nextPageToken, files(webViewLink, id, name)').execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

...
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def sms():

    return str(items)


    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I try to make reference to any gspread code within a Cloud Console, then I get an error; the error says something to the effect that port 8080 is no longer available. This error surfaces when I deploy to cloud run.

```
. Error: Deploying container to Cloud Run service [hello-world] in project [XXX] region [us-central1] ,Deploying... Creating Revision..............................................................................................................failed Deployment failed ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable
```

Comment: 1) Look in the Cloud Run logs. Your app is either taking too long processing the listing of files or your code is throwing an exception that you do not catch. 2) You should start the listener within 10 seconds of container start which means your global code might be interfering with the container starting correclty.

Comment: I will review the cloud run logs, but I also think it may be the second point with regards to the container and global variables being out of sync. One of the solutions I entertained was somehow important the gspread object within the Docker file. However, let me check logs and see if I can re-align things properly.